# Problem with hdf5r finding libhdf5_hl.so.100 file

Tags: r, hdf5

I'm trying to correctly load the R package hdf5r, well actually I want to use a dependency of hdf5r, but I'm running into problems with the hdf5r package. I've installed the hdf5r package, and no errors occurred during the installation. But when I load the package I get the following error:

```
> library(hdf5r)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘hdf5r’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/hdf5r/libs/hdf5r.so':
  libhdf5_hl.so.100: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have checked that both 
/usr/lib64/R/library/hdf5r/libs/hdf5r.so and the libhdf5_hl.so.100 files are present on my system. I installed the hdf5 package from source into /usr/local and have added the path /usr/local/lib to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable in my /usr/lib64/R/etc/Renviron file

```
> Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
[1] "/usr/local/lib"
```

I am on a RedHat 7 machine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, hdf5r can be loaded in the teminal R, however, it can't be loaded in the rstudio-server.

load the lib manully in r before load the hdf5r package

```
dyn.load('<your hdf5r lib path>/libhdf5_hl.so.100')
library(hdf5r)
```

Comment: I am running the R at a remote server which is not built by me. Do you know where I can find the libhdf5_hl.so.100 file? It doesn't seems to be located in the lib folder.

Comment: how interesting that I have asked the same question about an year ago!